# how to restrict a menu for some userd based on the value of a specific field?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

On my primary wp nav, I have a menu item named 'Research' which i want to only be shown for Researchers in wordpress.

Researchers will be defined by a user meta field called `wpum_relationship_to_lib` which is a multiple choices field including options like: researcher, student, employee and so on.

It is important that `researcher` must be one of the options the user choses to access that menu and that `wpum_relationship_to_lib` does not define a Wordpress role.

All menus are primary. Also, I need the menu to be hidden even before login. See my code below which is not restricting menu properly.

```php
function restrict_menu_to_researchers($items, $args) {
  
  // Check if the menu is assigned to the desired location
  if ($args->theme_location === 'primary') {

    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {

      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $relationship_values = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpum_relationship_to_lib', true);
            
      // Check if the user is the "researcher" 
      if (is_array($relationship_values) && in_array('researcher', $relationship_values)) {

        // Allow the menu for researchers
        return $items; 

      } else {
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
          if ($item->title == 'Research') {
            // Hide the "Research" menu for non-researchers
            unset($items[$key]); 
          }
        } 
      }
    } else {
      foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        if ($item->title == 'Research') {
          // Hide the "Research" menu for non-logged-in users
          unset($items[$key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'restrict_menu_to_researchers', 10, 2);
```

Comment: _"but does not work well"_ isn't a particularly useful problem description. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You need to debug, $item->title. What if you dump out at $item? Because if you follow the docs for `wp_nav_menu_objects` should be `menu_object` and when i dump menu object, its my post object, so if your `Research` is a post/page then it would be `$item->post_title == 'Research'`

Comment: @joshmoto thanks for your answer. actually I tested it in a test platform and it worked well. but in the main page it does not. although I did required changes. and I cannot disable plugins to see any conflict as everything is online. I thought maybe by changing codes can cover any possible conflict. and I'm afraid that your code didn't work neither.

Comment: @Mary.fa what is the exact array value for researcher in the user meta?

Comment: @Mary.fa i've updated my code because i was using `$menu_object->title` instead of `'researcher'` in my in_array function. Maybe that was the problem.

Comment: @joshmoto right. the exact word is 'researcher'. I will try it. but it had an issue that when user is not login all codes will be hidden. I changed that part for me. just FYKI. :) and thanks.

Comment: @Mary.fa you should consider accepting answer and closing question or provide more information on your live environment problem if you wish to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. it's interesting that it is case sensitive. and I just needed to use this code as follows. but it works in the test platform without this line. I didn't even know that might be for lower case:
(is_array($relationship_values) && in_array('researcher', array_map('strtolower', $relationship_values))) { ...

and thank you all for your kind help and time. –

Answer (score 0):

Actually ignore my comment, using `$item->title` seems to work as well.

I think your looping is wrong in yours. Try this version.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_objects/

See comments in php so you understand what is going on.

```php
function restrict_menu_to_researchers( $menu_objects, $args )
{

    // bail early if not on primary menu
    if ('primary' !== $args->theme_location) {
        return $menu_objects;
    }

    // if user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {

        // get relationship array
        $relationship_array = (array)get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(), 'wpum_relationship_to_lib', true);
        
        // foreach menu as key > menu object
        foreach ($menu_objects as $key => $menu_object) {

            // if menu object title is Research and is not in relationship array
            if ( $menu_object->title === 'Research' && !in_array('researcher', $relationship_array ) ) {

                // then restrict the menu object item
                unset( $menu_objects[$key] );
                
            }

        }

    }

    // return menu objects
    return $menu_objects;

}

add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'restrict_menu_to_researchers', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: @Mary.fa sorry just seen this, what do you mean the main page? It should work globally for any menu with the theme location.

Comment: we have a website which is online and a similar website just as the test. my codes work there very well as I want. but when I use them in the main website it doesn't show the menu at all. and these codes don't work either. even when I added the parts you forgot to mention. hope I made it clearer

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is mostly correct. However, there is a small issue in the conditional statement when checking the user's relationship values. I updated the code to ensure that the "Research" menu item is only shown to users who have selected "researcher" as one of their relationship values in the wpum_relationship_to_lib meta field. It also hides the "Research" menu for non-logged-in users. I did not tested the code, so any comment is welcome.
The code of #joshmoto is working, but in the foreach loop, the condition !in_array($menu_object->title, $relationship_array) checks if the menu object title is not in the relationship array. From what i understood from the question, you want to check if the value "researcher" is in the relationship array. Therefore, you should update the condition to in_array('researcher', $relationship_array).

```
function restrict_menu_to_researchers($items, $args) {
  // Check if the menu is assigned to the desired location
  if ($args->theme_location === 'primary') {
    // Check if the user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $relationship_values = get_user_meta($user_id, 'wpum_relationship_to_lib', true);
      
      // Check if the user has selected "researcher" as one of their relationship values
      if (is_array($relationship_values) && in_array('researcher', $relationship_values, true)) {
        // Allow the menu for researchers
        return $items;
      } else {
        // Hide the "Research" menu for non-researchers
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
          if ($item->title === 'Research') {
            unset($items[$key]);
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      // Hide the "Research" menu for non-logged-in users
      foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        if ($item->title === 'Research') {
          unset($items[$key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'restrict_menu_to_researchers', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. you are right. I needed only Researchers see the menu. but even by adding related codes to check that condition and trying your code, still the same result as my codes with the issue. my codes work in a test platform just like the main one. I don't realize what is changed in the main website. they are totally similar. but thanks for your time.

Comment: Ooops you're right my bad, fixed my code